# EntityManager query.getResultList() returning empty list

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am a beginner at Hibernate and JPA, I am trying to retrieve a `List` of items from my database via `EntityManager` `query.getResultList()` but it doesn't return anything. Here is my bean for searching the data: `

```
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
    import com.algaworks.financeiro.model.Lancamento;
    import com.algaworks.financeiro.util.JpaUtil;

    @ManagedBean
    @ViewScoped
    public class ConsultaLancamentosBean 
    {
       private List<Lancamento> lancamentos;
       public void consultar() 
      {
        EntityManager manager = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<Lancamento> query = manager.createQuery
       (
         "from Lancamento", Lancamento.class
       );
       this.lancamentos = query.getResultList();
       manager.close();
     }
     public List<Lancamento> getLancamentos() 
     {
       return lancamentos;
     }
  }
```

The view for the searching bean: `

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
   <h:head>
      <title>Consulta de lançamentos</title>
   </h:head>
   <h:body>
      <f:metadata>
         <f:viewAction action="#{consultaLancamentosBean.consultar}" />
      </f:metadata>
      <h1>Consulta de lançamentos</h1>
      <h:form id="frm">
         <h:dataTable value="#{consultaLancamentosBean.lancamentos}"
            var="lancamento" border="1" cellspacing="0"
            cellpadding="2">
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Pessoa"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.pessoa.nome}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Descrição"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.descricao}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Tipo"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.tipo}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Valor"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.valor}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Data de vencimento"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.dataVencimento}"/>
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
               <f:facet name="header">
                  <h:outputText value="Data de pagamento"/>
               </f:facet>
               <h:outputText value="#{lancamento.dataPagamento}"/>
            </h:column>
         </h:dataTable>
      </h:form>
   </h:body>
</html>
```

The `getLancamentos()` returns an empty list, does someone know why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Update:
I have verified that everything is right with the connection and all the tables have data, i changed the bean to have only one method: `

```
public List<Lancamento> getLancamentos() 
{   
  EntityManager manager = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();
  TypedQuery<Lancamento> query = manager.createQuery("SELECT lan FROM Lancamento    lan", Lancamento.class);            
  List<Lancamento> lancamentos;
  lancamentos = query.getResultList();
  return lancamentos;
 }
```

`And my new view is:`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
   xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
  <title>The size is:</title>
  <h:outputLabel value="#{consultaLancamentosBean.lancamentos}"> </h:outputLabel>
 </html>
```

`

But now, when i try to run the code it displays:
HTTP Status 500 - Could not initialize class
com.algaworks.financeiro.util.JpaUtil

I have already imported this class

Comment: how about you debug it? Look at the SQL generated. Look at the value of variables at different places. Look at why you have omitted "SELECT lan" from the JPQL.

Comment: i omitted the "SELECT lan" because an ebbok told me to do so, it said you dont have to specify the columns when working with JPQL

Comment: your book is wrong. The JPA spec says clearly enough that "SELECT {alias}" is mandatory. Only bad documentation says things that are non-portable

Comment: thanks for the advice, i fugured that too hehe, gonna find a new book then. Can you suggest me something good that covers jsf and primefaces as well? something from 2014 - 2016 ? I mean something recent

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TypedQuery<Lancamento> query = manager.createQuery("SELECT lan FROM Lancamento lan", Lancamento.class);
lancamentos = query.getResultList();
```

Your query is now specifying what to `SELECT`

Comment: updated the code but nothing changes at all, by the way, ill post the view for the searching bean as well

Comment: @ThalesRuano display the result of `query.getResultList();` before closing the manager. There is a chance you are receiving them but they aren't being displayed

Comment: it doesn't work as well, could you point me an advice on how to discover if the bean is really getting the data from database?

Comment: @ThalesRuano The best way to check if the query receives data from the DB is to display it's content or size before exiting the method. For now, don't worry about displaying them on the HTML, have them display in your code. Secondly, check if the connection is good. Are you connected to the right Database and do your tables have any information in them. Is your query currently returning something?